# how can i select few or null in a grouped query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In my table containing the profiles of the users, I have a column that specifies the groups the users are in, and this is mapped to another table with the foreign key structure in the form of id.

What I want to do is to find out which group has no users or which has fewer users with a single query.

if we imagine the following as my profile table

```
+------------+-----------------+
| id| uid   | user_group_labels|
+------------+-----------------+
| 1 | xxxxxxxx |    5051288    |
| 2 | yyyyyyyy |    5051288    |
| 3 | zzzzzzzz |    5051286    |
| 4 | aaaaaaaa |    5051286    |
| 5 | bbbbbbbb |    5051286    |
```

And if we imagine the following as my user groups table

```
        +---------------------------+
        |    id.  |user_group_name  |
        +---------------------------+
        | 5051288 |    xxxxxxxx     |
        | 5051286 |    yyyyyyyy     |
        | 4906315 |    zzzzzzzz     |
```

The output I expect should be as follows

```
        +---------------------------+
        |    id.  |user_group_name  |
        +---------------------------+
        | 4906315 |    zzzzzzzz     |
```

Because the group with id 4906315 is not assigned to any user and it needs to be assigned to a user.

Not only they are not assigned but if there is no group with id 4906315, the group with id 5051288 should output to me because it is less assigned than the other group.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Sample data and desired output are highly welcome

Comment: provide table structure, sample data and your desired output

Comment: Sorry for not adding examples, I've included the examples in the question. @Sergey

Comment: Sorry for not adding examples, I've included the examples in the question. @Hana

Answer (score -1):

> find out which group has no users or which has fewer users with a single query.

```sql
SELECT groups.group_name, COUNT(users.group_id) users_amount
FROM `groups`
LEFT JOIN users USING (group_id)
GROUP BY 1
HAVING users_amount <= @users_per_group
-- ORDER BY users_amount
```

where `@users_per_group` is the users count limit for "fewer users" criteria.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5C5KepvRUjzpnw1wsqGHvd/0

Comment: Hey @Akina thanks for your answer, i add some examples on my question. Maybe you wanna look and change your answer.

Comment: @UtkuErem Demo fiddle added. Adapt the query to your structure by changing the names of tables/columns. PS. You related columns have different names - so use ON clause instead of USING.

Comment: thank you very much for your hands, Is there a way I can produce this output without giving the number of users per group statically?

Comment: @UtkuErem But this value must exist. It may be a parameter whose value is provided dynamically. It may be calculated from existing data (for example, like some percent of maximal users per group amount). Also you may select some predefined amount of the rows with the least users amount (for example, 5 rows - in this case you must remove HAVING, uncomment ORDER BY and add according LIMIT). You may even select all rows with specified ordering (remove HAVING, uncomment ORDER BY) and filter this rowset on the client side... You're the only who can decide what you need in.